# Backbone Js - Setting Geo location variables [undefined variables]

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, geolocation

I am trying to set a variable to hold latitude and longitude variables to plot on Google Maps (I am trying to have it set up later where I can later add to a collection). I am running console long test and found out my variables from my function is setting the coords. How would I be able to do so? (Sorry I'm still new to JavaScript and Backbone.Js)

```
    var Area = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#load',

    initialize: function(){
        //this.getLocation();
        this.canvasId = 'map';
        this.area = '<h2>Area of BAC</h2><div id="'+this.canvasId+'"></div>';
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.area);
        this.getLocation();
        console.log(this.lat+' '+this.lng+' - Confirmed');
        //this.createMap(this.lat, this.lng);
        //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', this.createMap);

    },

    createMap: function(lat, lng){
        //var mlat = lat;
        //var mlong = lng;
        //alert(lat+' '+lng);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7430473, -74.1777488),
            //center: new google.maps.LatLng(mlat, mlng),
            zoom: 15
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.canvasId), mapOptions);
    },

    getLocation: function(){
        console.log('Test - getGeolocation');
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setLatLng);
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setLatLng);
        }else{
            alert('Either you have no internet connection or your browser is not supported');
        }
    },

    setLatLng: function(position){
        console.log('Test - setLatLng');
        this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        console.log('Test - setLatLng-lat');
        this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log('Test - setLatLng-lng');
        console.log(this.lat+' '+this.lng);
    },

    throwErr: function(){
        alert('Cannot get coords');
    }

});
```

My Console log:

```
Test - getGeolocation Area.js:32
undefined undefined - Confirmed Area.js:13
Test - setLatLng Area.js:42
Test - setLatLng-lat Area.js:44
Test - setLatLng-lng Area.js:46
19.7180872 -89.0860836
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess: The problem seems to be with the `this` reference.

Update `getLocation` method to below :

```
getLocation: function(){
    var self = this;
    console.log('Test - getGeolocation');
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setLatLng);
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            self.setLatLng(position);
        });
    }else{
        alert('Either you have no internet connection or your browser is not supported');
    }
},
```